# How can I insert pagination in my search engine?

Tags: php, pagination, search-engine

How can I insert pagination in my search engine search.php page?

If there is 1 page, I do not want the **Previous** button and the **Next** button.

If there are 2 pages and I am on the first page, I hope that I can have the **Next** button.

If there are 2 pages and I am on the second page, I also hope that I can only have the **Previous** button.

This is my current code, hope that you can help me:

```
<?php
//php code goes here
include 'connect.php'; // for database connection
include 'script_suggestion.php';
include 'script_close_suggestion_box.php';
$query = $_GET['q']; // query
$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$page_number = $_GET['page'];

if (!$page_number);
$page_number = 0;

$results_per_page = 10;

$next = $page_number + $results_per_page;
$prev = $page_number - $results_per_page;

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Brandon's Search Engine
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #title a {
                font-size: 17pt;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 2px;
                border-color: black;
                text-decoration: underline;
                width: 544px;
            }
            #search-result {
                display: block;
                border: 1px solid grey;
                border-color: grey;
            }
            #search-result:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd;
                width: 544px;
            }
            #link {
                font-size: 17pt;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 2px;
                width: 544px;
            }
            #description {
                font-size: 17pt;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 2px;
                width: 544px;
            }
            #search-page-number {
                display: block;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                border: 1px solid gray;
                margin: 2px;
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 2px;
                padding-top: 2px;
                list-style: none;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #search-page-number:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
            #suggestion {
                border: 1px solid black;
                visibility: hidden;
                position: fixed;
                background-color: white;
                z-index: 10;
            }
            #suggestion a {
                font-size: 12pt;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                width: 548px;
                height: auto;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 2px;
            }
            #suggestion a:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd;
                width: 544px;
                padding: 2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="search.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h2>
                            Brandon's Search Engine
                        </h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']); ?>" name="q" style="height: 27px; width: 550px; padding: 2px" name="q"
                               onkeyup="getSuggestion(this.value)" autocomplete="off" onblur="closeBox()" placeholder="Search Now"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" style="height: auto; width: 60px; padding: 2px" />

                        <div id="suggestion" style="width: 548px">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        //SQL query
                        $stmt = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' OR keywords LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' OR link LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' LIMIT " . $page_number . " , $results_per_page";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error($con));
                        $number_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                        $x++;
                        if($x==1)
                        if ($number_of_result < 1) {
                            echo "<b>No results found!</b>";
                            echo "<p>";
                            echo "Your search - <b>$query</b>" . " - did not match any documents. Please try different keywords.";
                        } elseif ($number_of_result > 1) {
                            echo "<b>$number_of_result results found!</b>";
                            echo "<p>";
                            //results found here and display them
                            $index = 1;
                            while (($row = \mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && ($index < 10)) {//10 results per page
                                $title = $row["title"];
                                $description = $row["description"];
                                $link = $row["link"];
                                echo "<div id='search-result'>";
                                echo "<div id='title'><a href='$link'>" . $title . "</a></div>";
                                //echo "<br />";
                                echo "<div id='link'><small>" . $link . "</small></div>";
                                //echo "<p>";
                                echo "<div id='description'><small>" . $description . "</small></div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "<br />";
                                $index++;
                            }
                        } elseif ($number_of_result = 1) {
                            echo "<b>$number_of_result result found!</b>";
                            echo "<p>";
                            //results found here and display them
                            $index = 1;
                            while (($row = \mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && ($index < 10)) {//10 results per page
                                $title = $row["title"];
                                $description = $row["description"];
                                $link = $row["link"];
                                echo "<div id='search-result'>";
                                echo "<div id='title'><a href='$link'>" . $title . "</a></div>";
                                //echo "<br />";
                                echo "<div id='link'><small>" . $link . "</small></div>";
                                echo "<br />";
                                echo "<div id='description'><small>" . $description . "</small></div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "<br />";
                                $index++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo 1; ?>" />
                        <div id="page-number">
                            Select Page Number:
                            <?php
                            //ie if 35 results are therer then we require 4 pages that are 0 to max_page_number
                            //current page number is equal to page_number
                            $max_page_number = $number_of_result / 10;
                            //echo $max_page_number;
                            echo "<ul>";
                            //both the condition are not the neccesary
                            if(!$page_number <= 0)
                            {
                                //print the link to previous page
                                echo "<li id='search-page-number'>";
                                echo "<a href=search.php?q=$query&page=$prev" . ">Previous</a>";
                                echo "</li>";
                            }
                            $i = 1;
                            for($index = 0; $index < $number_of_result; $index=$index+$results_per_page)
                            {
                                echo "<li id='search-page-number'>";
                                echo "<a href=search.php?q=$query&page=$i>";
                                echo $i++ . "</a>";
                                echo "</li>";
                            }
                            if($page_number < $number_of_result - $results_per_page)
                            {
                                //print the link to next page
                                echo "<li id='search-page-number'>";
                                echo "<a href=search.php?q=$query&page=$next" . ">Next</a>";
                                echo "</li>";
                            }
                            echo "</ul>";
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        To insert your site in result fill in the form at <a href="insert.php">here</a>.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591660/adding-pagination-to-bing-search-engine

Comment: I have read that question before I post my question. But I still can't get the solution.

Comment: the content of the `<title>` tag made me laugh, nice one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//php code goes here
include 'connect.php'; // for database connection
include 'script_suggestion.php';
include 'script_close_suggestion_box.php';
$query = $_GET['q']; // query
$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$page_number = (int)$_GET['page'];

if (!$page_number) 
$page_number = 0;

$results_per_page = 10;

$next = $page_number + $results_per_page;
$prev = $page_number - $results_per_page;

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Brandon's Search Engine
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #title a {
                font-size: 17pt;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 2px;
                border-color: black;
                text-decoration: underline;
                width: 544px;
            }
            #search-result {
                display: block;
                border: 1px solid grey;
                border-color: grey;
            }
            #search-result:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd;
                width: 544px;
            }
            #link {
                font-size: 17pt;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 2px;
                width: 544px;
            }
            #description {
                font-size: 17pt;
                margin: 5px;
                padding: 2px;
                width: 544px;
            }
            #search-page-number {
                display: block;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                border: 1px solid gray;
                margin: 2px;
                padding-left: 5px;
                padding-right: 5px;
                padding-bottom: 2px;
                padding-top: 2px;
                list-style: none;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #search-page-number:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd;
            }
            #suggestion {
                border: 1px solid black;
                visibility: hidden;
                position: fixed;
                background-color: white;
                z-index: 10;
            }
            #suggestion a {
                font-size: 12pt;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                width: 548px;
                height: auto;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 2px;
            }
            #suggestion a:hover {
                background-color: #dddddd;
                width: 544px;
                padding: 2px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="search.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h2>
                            Brandon's Search Engine
                        </h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']); ?>" name="q" style="height: 27px; width: 550px; padding: 2px" name="q"
                               onkeyup="getSuggestion(this.value)" autocomplete="off" onblur="closeBox()" placeholder="Search Now"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" style="height: auto; width: 60px; padding: 2px" />

                        <div id="suggestion" style="width: 548px">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php
  //count 
$count_sql = "SELECT count(*) as c FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' OR keywords LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' OR link LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' ";
$search_count = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$count_sql));
$number_of_result = $search_count['c'];
                        //SQL query
                        $stmt = "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE title LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' OR keywords LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' OR link LIKE '%" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$query) . "%' LIMIT " . $page_number . " , $results_per_page";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con,$stmt) or die(mysqli_error($con));
//$number_of_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                        $x++;
                        if($x==1)
                        if ($number_of_result < 1) {
                            echo "<b>No results found!</b>";
                            echo "<p>";
                            echo "Your search - <b>$query</b>" . " - did not match any documents. Please try different keywords.";
                        } elseif ($number_of_result > 1) {
                            echo "<b>$number_of_result results found!</b>";
                            echo "<p>";
                            //results found here and display them
                            $index = 1;
                            while (($row = \mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && ($index < 10)) {//10 results per page
                                $title = $row["title"];
                                $description = $row["description"];
                                $link = $row["link"];
                                echo "<div id='search-result'>";
                                echo "<div id='title'><a href='$link'>" . $title . "</a></div>";
                                //echo "<br />";
                                echo "<div id='link'><small>" . $link . "</small></div>";
                                //echo "<p>";
                                echo "<div id='description'><small>" . $description . "</small></div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "<br />";
                                $index++;
                            }
                        } elseif ($number_of_result == 1) {
                            echo "<b>$number_of_result result found!</b>";
                            echo "<p>";
                            //results found here and display them
                            $index = 1;
                            while (($row = \mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) && ($index < 10)) {//10 results per page
                                $title = $row["title"];
                                $description = $row["description"];
                                $link = $row["link"];
                                echo "<div id='search-result'>";
                                echo "<div id='title'><a href='$link'>" . $title . "</a></div>";
                                //echo "<br />";
                                echo "<div id='link'><small>" . $link . "</small></div>";
                                echo "<br />";
                                echo "<div id='description'><small>" . $description . "</small></div>";
                                echo "</div>";
                                echo "<br />";
                                $index++;
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="0" />
<div id="page-number">
                            Select Page Number:
                            <?php

                            //ie if 35 results are therer then we require 4 pages that are 0 to max_page_number
                            //current page number is equal to page_number

    $max_page_number = ceil($number_of_result / $results_per_page);
                            //echo $max_page_number;
                            echo "<ul>";
                            //both the condition are not the neccesary
if ($max_page_number > 2) { // if more than 2 pages 

  if ($page_number > 0 ) { //Previous
    echo "<li id='search-page-number'>";
    echo "<a href=search.php?q=$query&page=".($page_number -  $results_per_page).">Previous</a>";
    echo "</li>";
  }

  for($index = 0 ; $index < $max_page_number ; $index++)
    {




      echo "<li id='search-page-number'>";
      echo "<a href=search.php?q=$query&page=".($index * $results_per_page).">";
      echo ($index + 1) . "</a>";
      echo "</li>";

    }

  if (($page_number + $results_per_page) < $number_of_result ) { //Next
    echo "<li id='search-page-number'>";
    echo "<a href=search.php?q=$query&page=".($page_number +  $results_per_page).">Next</a>";
    echo "</li>";
  }

} elseif (($max_page_number == 2 ) ) {

  echo "<li id='search-page-number'>";
  echo "<a href=search.php?q=$query&page=".($page_number == 0 ? 10 : 0).">".($page_number == 0 ? "Next":"Previous" )."</a>";
  echo "</li>";
} elseif (($max_page_number == 1 ) ) {

  echo "<li id='search-page-number'>";
  echo "<a href=search.php?q=$query&page=0>1</a>";
  echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        To insert your site in result fill in the form at <a href="insert.php">here</a>.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which part should I insert this? Sorry for asking this question.

Comment: In your code, there are lots of errors, I will write the right version after half an hour.

Comment: It does not work. Where can I change how many results per page?

Comment: Please check your code there have some errors, like here elseif ($number_of_result = 1) { you must use == 1 and you must change  $page_number = $_GET['page']; to $page_number = (int)$_GET['page'];

Comment: Do you have any other ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please use the new version.

Comment: Thank you. It works great. But how could I add the **Previous** button & the **Next** button beside the numbers?

Comment: If the result number is between 10 and 20, the previous & the next button will appear.

Comment: Then if I change my results per page, how can I make those two buttons to appear?

Comment: Did you mean that you want to show the Previous and the Next button on more than 2 pages?

Comment: Please use the new version.

Comment: When there is only 1 page of result, how can I have the page number 1 under the **Select Page Number** section?

Comment: Where there are 2 pages, can I have the **page number** and the **next** button? Sorry for not replying, went for Christmas celebration!

Comment: Let me know what other problems you are having.